# How to use a custom Window with Caliburn.Micro 2?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I would like to use my own class that extends *Window* to display dialogs in an MVVM environment using Caliburn.Micro.

I have read on how I can customize the CM-provided window by either overriding the *EnsureWindow* method in *WindowManager*, or by accessing the default *WindowManager* instance in my view model and passing a settings dictionary to the "ShowDialog" method. Nevertheless, what I really need is to use my own class, because it contains other elements that just can't be supplied to the default window by simply setting some properties.

For clarity, I'm OK with using the default *Window* class for my root view.

Is this possible at all? I'll be glad to expand on my rationale if somehow my question doesn't make sense...

Thanks in advance to the community!

Comment: You don't have to use WindowManager that is built in.. I actually use the Telerik RadWindow for one of my applications and use IWindowManager and extend where I need different functionality.

Comment: @mvermef: thanks for the response! Just to clarify, are you saying that you subclass WindowManager and override, for instance, the "ShowWindow" method, supplying your own custom window? Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: @mvermef: After mulling over your response for a few minutes, I went ahead and overrode the EnsureWindow of the WindowManager class, replacing the Window instance created there with my own class that extends Window. That seemed to do the trick. Is that more or less what you did with your Telerik RadWindow?

Comment: Yes, glad it worked out for you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestion from @mvermef, I did some research and came up with a solution. It consists of overriding the *EnsureWindow* method of the *WindowManager* class. Here's an example:

```
protected override Window EnsureWindow(object model, object view, bool isDialog)
{
    var window = view as Window;
    if (window == null)
    {
        window = new MyCustomWindowClass
        {                 
            SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight
        };

        // I defined a ContentControl "WindowContent" in MyCustomWindow  
        // class to insert the window's contents
        ((MyCustomWindowClass)window).WindowContent.Content = view;
        window.SetValue(View.IsGeneratedProperty, true);

        var owner = InferOwnerOf(window);
        if (owner != null)
        {
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
            window.Owner = owner;
        }
        else
        {
            window.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterScreen;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        var owner = InferOwnerOf(window);
        if (owner != null && isDialog)
        {
            window.Owner = owner;
        }
    }

    return window;
}
```